# Measure execution time of a command including expansion of command substitution

Tags: shell, zsh, time, command-substitution

How would I go about measuring the running time of commands that are expanded by the shell?

For example:

```
➜ time sleep $(sleep 3; echo 1)
sleep $(sleep 3; echo 1)  0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 1.003 total
```

ignores the time of the substituted command.

How to measure the total time instead, to get four seconds as output?

Comment: I just tried this in bash and it works as expected : 0m4.104s

Comment: @XTian Then, this might be `zsh` specific. I've now added a tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer was simpler than I thought it would be. Credit to [John B](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21820530/1916449), one can use a sub-shell `(...)` for this:

```
➜ time (sleep $(sleep 3; echo 1))
( sleep $(sleep 3; echo 1); )  0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 4.007 total
```

Answer (score 0):

That happens in zsh:

```
$ zsh -c 'time sleep $(sleep 3; echo 1)'
sleep $(sleep 3; echo 1)  0,00s user 0,00s system 0% cpu 1,001 total
```

But not in bash (or ksh):

```
$  bash -c 'time sleep $(sleep 3; echo 1)'

real    0m4.003s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

One simple solution will be to use some from of grouping:

```
$ zsh -c 'time ( sleep $(sleep 3; echo 1); )'
( sleep $(sleep 3; echo 1); )  0,00s user 0,00s system 0% cpu 4,003 total
```